# Strongly typed view model and re-rendering select list if Model is not valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, repository, viewmodel

Ok, I looked a bit and couldn't find a good answer to this question.

Using ASP MVC3 I have a strongly typed ViewModel that has a list of custom objects retrieved from a repository.  I render out using `DropDownListFor` as a dropdown selection.  A value is selected and during the post I have a custom binder that rebinds my selected value to the custom object....Life is good...

I check my Model.IsValid and it is not valid for some reason.  Uh, oh...I need to display the view again but I dont have the complete list of all  options.  Is there a way to repopulate all of the select option values in the custom model binder or some other method or do I have to hit my repository again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit your repository again. Implement caching in your repository using a MemoryCache to save on DB hits and cache by key. This is the advantage of the repository pattern and the caller is unaware. Since by definition a repository is essentially an in memory representation this works out great.

Check out the implementation here it's similar to what I use and it works great.
http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/

Your currently selected item should remain selected since the HTML helpers read it from the posted data and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I figured.  I haven't gotten to the caching part yet, it's on my todo list :)

Answer (score 0):

I typically rebuild the list again and send back to the View.  Often I'll use a factory method to inflate the viewmodel(s) with the necessary list(s).  Hopefully, an invalid model will be a rare occurrence due to client-side validation in addition to the server side you're working with now.

Comment: I agree.  I hope the client side validation should catch these issues.  I only came across this issue because I developed a custom ValidationAttribute and I hadn't implemeneted the client code yet.